# Materialize Parallax Initialization on Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, materialize

I'm using materializecss as a front-end framework for my personal website I am currently developing. I used their starter Parallax template and everything works, but for some reason my Parallax images are not showing. I believe it has something to do with the initialization.

snippet of one of the parallax for the HTML:

```
<template name="parall">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="/public/background1.jpg">
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.parall.onRendered(function(){
        $(".parallax").parallax();
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
    });
}
```

Comment: A quick test you can try is open up the console when your template is loaded and try `$(".parallax").parallax();` see if that makes a difference. I also added `z-index:0` to `.parallax` and that fixed some of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rendering your images with css?

```
.parallax {
 background-image: url("/background1.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try removing "public" from your img src, and instead use "/background1.jpg". [ Assuming "public" directory is in your route project folder ].

You dont have to specify "public" while accessing resources stored in public directory. It is one among the few reserved directory names in meteor structure.

Comment: I tried this and also tried using a different image and it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div.parallax in div.parallax-container

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the div in a parallax-container as already posted

```
<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="/images/parallax1.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

and add the following in your CSS

```
.parallax{
    position:static!important 
}
```